# Is there a cost for deleting a GSI in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a GSI with 150 million records and I don't need the GSI anymore, I would like to delete it and I can't find any documentation pointing to the costs of deleting a GSI. Will it cost me to completely delete a GSI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting a DynamoDB table is like any other control plane operations and does not incur CUs. That said, I am opening a ticket to have [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html#GSI.OnlineOps.Deleting) and section updated.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, I appreciate your comment

Comment: I updated my response and I confirmed it is a control plan op, not a data plan op.

Comment: Great, I will delete mine and let you know also

Comment: I checked my billing and it cost nothing to delete a GSI with 150 million records